# Problema no deploy de uma aplicação no tomcat

Tags: java

Tenho uma aplicação rodando local, onde fiz deploy no tomcat local e funciona perfeitamente. Instalei a mesma versão do tomcat e do banco de dados postgres em outra máquina, que no caso será o servidor, mas não está funcionando, dá os seguintes erros:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Não é possível criar instância para·a classe: control.ControlUsuarioAfastamento.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at model.EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager(EntityManagerUtil.java:14)
    at dao.UsuarioAfastamentoDAO.<init>(UsuarioAfastamentoDAO.java:14)
    at control.ControlUsuarioAfastamento.<init>(ControlUsuarioAfastamento.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:149)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:47)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:414)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:129)
    ... 108 more
```

Já tentei de tudo e nada da certo.

Comment: certo...tentei pesquisar erro a erro disso, e vi que o banco de dados, os dois tem o mesmo nome...ele da erro que parece ser da chamada do driver jdbc, entao coloquei os libs do projeto dentro da pasta de libs do tomcat..ele da um erro que parece dizer que a porta 5432 do tomcat nao esta disponivel, sendo que ja verifiquei e esta tudo certo. o problema é o banco de dados, pois acabei de subir um .war que nao tem conexao com banco. o erro esta no banco e na conexao, sabe como resolver isso por favor?

Comment: com certeza o poblema é o banco de dados...alguem saberia como fazer a aplicação no tomcat enchegar o banco de dados?

Comment: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`: como é configurado o datasource na sua aplicação? Deve ter alguma configuração errada aí, provavelmente usuário/senha

Comment: cara acho que o problema é que a aplicação nao consegue ver o banco de dados...comoo eu faria pra colocar o banco de dados no servidor, e apontar a aplicação para ele? usuario e senha ja conferi, ta tudo certo

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to
>   localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct
>   and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP

De forma geral existem poucas situações

1) O ip do target está errado.

2) O target está com a porta 5432 bloqueada

3) O postgres não está configurado para [aceitar conexão externa](http://www.prideti.com/2015/04/liberando-acesso-ao-banco-de-dados-postgresql-no-windows/)

Uma possibilidade, remotamente possível, é haver diferença nas bibliotecas (geralmente versões) do hibernate.

Comment: estou tentando fazer o uso remoto do postgres, e estou recebendo o seguinte erro: nenhuma entrada no pg_hba conf para máquina "10.12.133.26", usuario "postgres", banco de dados "postgres",  ssl desabilitado..sabe o que seria isso ?

Comment: Provavelmente sim.  [Este arquivo](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) contém algumas configurações para liberação de acesso.

Comment: À partir do minuto 24:40 ele faz a configuração que você precisa, se tiver um tempinho assiste tudo..... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67XGzdzv9k0

Comment: cara deu certo aqui, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Agora preciso saber como distribuir essa aplicação na rede, onde eu passaria o endereco ip / nome da aplicação, tipo : 10.12.133.26/minhaAplicação

Comment: Não entendi o problema. Seu container já está acessando o servidor de banco de dados, os usuários só precisam conhecer o endereço do container, algo do tipo http : // ip_tomcat:porta_tomcat/nome_aplicacao.

Comment: Obrigado cara deu certo, valeu mesmo. Só mais uma dúvida, no caminho de conexão com o banco de dados, estou passando ....localhost:5432..., e não está funcionado, devo passar o  ip junto, ou algo do tipo? Obrigado

Comment: consegui resolver aqui, muito obrigado a todos pela ajuda